# Отображение фото места на точке в Яндекс картах

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Как сделать в яндекс картах на точке (на месте), чтобы показывалась фотография этого места? Хочу прикрепить фото здания к этой точке.

Comment: Вот два готовых решения. Адаптируйте под свои нужды: - [Размещаем свои фотографии на Яндекс.Карте](http://webmap-blog.ru/yandex-maps/razmeshhaem-svoi-fotografii-na-yandeks-karte); - [Размещаем flash-видео в балуне на Яндекс.Карте](http://webmap-blog.ru/yandex-maps/razmeshhaem-flash-video-v-balune-na-yandeks-karte). Пользуйтесь.